# Perpendicular continuous function of $R^3$ unit vectors?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, geometry, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

Let S be the set of all unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Does there exist a *continuous* function $f$ from $S \to S$ such that $\forall v \in S: v \cdot f(v) = 0 $ ?

If so, what is one such function?  If not, why not?

Comment: No, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem#:~:text=The%20hairy%20ball%20theorem%20of,even%2Ddimensional%20n%2Dspheres.